# Mysql, make a DISTINCT with only one colone while showing the other

Tags: mysql, count, distinct

I've a table like this :

```
ID USER PRODUCT
1 user1 product1
2 user2 product2
3 user2 product2
4 user3 product3
```

I want to count how many DIFFERENT USERS bought each product.

I expect something like this :

```
PRODUCT count
product1  1
product2  1
product3  1
```

I've many things like this, but don't have the result I expect.

```
SELECT DISTINCT PRODUCT, COUNT(ID) as count FROM `test`
group by USER
```

(the code below provides this result :

```
PRODUCT count
site1     1
site2     2
site3     1
```

The second ligne should be 1 and not 2.
Any advices ?
Thanks

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to take the distinct count:

```
SELECT PRODUCT, COUNT(DISTINCT USER) AS count
FROM test
GROUP BY PRODUCT;
```

Your current query is using `SELECT DISTINCT` which will attempt to apply distinct to everything being selected.  But, you only want it applied to count of users.

[image]

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

Try the below:

```
SELECT product, COUNT(DISTINCT user) 
FROM table 
WHERE 1 = 1
GROUP BY product
```